# SDP problem with Schur complement-like constraint

Tags: matrices, optimization, projection-matrices, semidefinite-programming

I'm interested in what we can conclude about the following question. Let $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be in the convex hull of projection matrices of rank at most $k$ (equivalently, $\mathbf{0} \preceq \mathbf{Y} \preceq \mathbb{I}_n$ and $\text{trace}(\mathbf{Y}) \leq k$), and let $\mathbf{Z_2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ be known. Is there an "easy" way to solve:
\begin{align*}
    \min_{\mathbf{Z_1}, \mathbf{Z_3}} \quad &
    \langle \mathbf{Z_1}, \mathbf{Y} \rangle + \langle \mathbf{Z_3}, \mathbb{I}_k \rangle \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad &
    \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{Z_1} & \mathbf{Z_2} \\ \mathbf{Z_2}^\top & \mathbf{Z_3}
    \end{pmatrix} \succeq \mathbf{0} \\
    & \mathbf{Z_1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \ \mathbf{Z_3} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}
\end{align*}

Comment: What do you mean by "an easy way"? Also, what are your decision variables here?

Comment: Here, I know I can solve this as an SDP problem via Mosek, for example. I am looking to see if there is an easier way (possibly a closed-form solution, or a computationally quick way e.g. the power method for eigenvalues).
The decision variables are $\mathbf{Z_1}$ and $\mathbf{Z_3}$ - sorry for not being clear!

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: What is the dimension of the matrices here ($n$ and $k$) in your problem? SDP solvers are quite quick to solve reasonably large problems.

Comment: @KBS we usually have $k << n$, and typically $k < 5$. It's true that the SDP solvers would be reasonably quick but I want to solve many of these in a helper procedure.

Comment: @rodrigo-de-azevedo This is a problem I'm facing in my research and wanted to see if others had encountered anything similar!

Comment: @SeanLo Ok but what is $n$ then? The problem is that without context it is difficult to give a proper answer. In fact, solving this problem may not even give a good solution to your initial problem. See the so-called XY-problem.

Comment: @KBS thank you for your patience - I guess in this context I'm interested in whether there are ways to solve this for $n = 20, k = 2$. For an example of what I am talking about, we know that the following problem:
$$ \min_{\delta \geq 0} \{ \delta : \mathbf{H} + \delta \mathbb{I} \succeq \mathbf{0} \}
$$
for $\mathbf{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ known, can be computed "easily" by taking $\delta^*$ to be the negative of the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{H}$, which is "easier than" solving the corresponding SDP problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the convex hull of *orthogonal* projection matrices of rank at most $k$ is defined by $\mathbf{0} \preceq \mathbf{Y} \preceq \mathbf{I}_n$ and $\mbox{trace}(\mathbf{Y}) \leq k$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, we should be looking at _orthogonal_ projections instead of just projections. And yes, this result comes from [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0613006).

Comment: Then why don't you include the link in the question? Mention which section of the paper is relevant.

Comment: Exactly, *orthogonal* projectors. I emphasised the orthogonal part because you forgot to mention it.